# Xpath 2.0 online Checker

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Is there any plugin or software where i can check the functions of Xpath 2.0 ??

Currently i am using Xpath Checker (ff Plugin) which only supports Xpath 1.0.

Comment: Not online, but there are well-known XSLT 2.0 and XQuery IDEs, such as oXygen or StylusStudio, or BaseX (for XQuery only)

Comment: The oXygen is showing so much errors while applying xpath on the HTML page. How come i ignore these error and see the corresponding output ??

Comment: XPath can be applied on *well-formed* XML documents. HTML in general isn't well-formed XML. You need either to use some tool that accepts HTML and behaves as if it is well-formed XML, or you need as a first step to convert the HTML into a well-formed XML document. One tool for such conversion is XML-Tidy.

Comment: I am using HTML Tidy to convert the HTML into XMl and using the Converted XML in the OXygen Tool to write the Xpath 2.0. But the oxygen tool is showing me the different errors in the layout. is there any way to create Error free XML .. ??

Comment: The way to create an "error-free" XML document is by writing it and adhering to the rules for XML document well-formedness. As for converting HTML to XML, one good tool I am aware of is HTML Tidy

Answer (score 4):

There is an online XPath 2.0 tool called [PathEnq](http://www.qutoric.com/xslt/analyser/xpathtool.html) that might suit.

[image]

The tool runs client-side by using the [Saxon-CE](http://saxonica.com) XSLT 2.0 processor (a JavaScript application) as a 'host' and dynamically generating XSLT based on your expression. XPath variables and namespaces are supported.

Comment: Phill, by "online" the OP understands a tool that is hosted and accessible by its URL -- not a client-side tool.

Comment: Well, it's accessible by its URL - whether it does its work server-side or client-side should be somewhat irrelevant, surely?

Comment: @dimitre Perhaps my use of the term 'client-side' is ambiguous in this context, should I say 'within the browser'? Regardless, clicking the link (which I'm not sure you have) one gets the response one would hope and expect from on online tool - i.e. a working application ready to go.

Comment: @pgfearo and Michael, Yes, you are right -- maybe the detail that the code is downloaded and cached on the client is irrelevant. I think that this may be pointed out even as an advantage -- in the case the "server" is down, your "online" tool continues to work "offline" :)

Comment: @Shivam I see, so when you say 'online checker' you don't want an online tool, you want an offline tool (a plugin downloaded and installed) that queries online resources. I will try to modify the app to let you query online resources by giving you a 'browser window' (an iframe) within the app but don't want to tie it to a specific version of a specific browser by making it a plugin.

Comment: @pgfearo thanx for guiding me. I am eagerly waiting for such a tool. it 'll be a great help indeed.

Comment: @Shivam - Unfortunately, due to cross-site scripting restrictions I can't provide the 'browser window' without setting up my server as a reverse proxy - exposing it to various kinds of attack. I may need to revisit the 'plug-in option' after all...

Comment: @pgfearo oky. Currently i am using HTML Tidy to convert HTML into XML Pages and then Oxygen tool(Saxon Processor) to process my Xpath 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using online xpath tester [xpather](http://xpather.com/) which works really nice.

Note: It's xpath 2.0 support is currently in beta.